# Using jQuery to provide onclick event within inside a Jinja2 loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, jinja2

I'm using Python / Flask / Jinja2

Within the for loop I want a click on the {{ place.place_photo }} to toggle the details. I had it working except it toggled all of the items instead of just one at a time.

**HTML:**

```
{% if places %}
    <div class="col-md-12 company_content_img_all">
        {% for place in places %}
            <div class="row col-md-3" id="place_pic">
                <div class="company_img_block company_btn1">
                    <img src="{{ place.place_photo }}" class="popos_img" type="button" id="button_{{ place.place_photo }}">
                    <div class="company_img_desc">{{ place.title }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div hidden class="col-md-9" id="details">
                <div id="details_{{ place.place_photo }}">
                    <p>
                    <b>Description:</b> {{ place.description }}<br/>
                    <b>Address:</b> {{ place.address }}<br/>
                    <b>Neighborhood:</b> {{ place.neighborhood }}<br/>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

---

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        $('.button').each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){
                $('#details_'+$(this).attr('place_photo')).toggle();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to attach `click` event handler within loop. You can achieve it by following way:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //attach the click event to all <img> tag having class 'popos_img'
        //here no need of any for loop
        $('.popos_img').click(function(){
            var currentId = $(this).attr("id");
            var variablePart = currentId.replace("button_",""); //grab the only variable part so that we can formulate the associated id of div
            $('#details_'+variablePart).toggle(); //toggle the associated div
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also I will suggest you to avoid giving fixed `id` like `<div hidden class="col-md-9" id="details">` whenever you are generating HTML within loop. `id` should be unique and it shouldn't be duplicated within your HTML page

Comment: Ah duh, id's and loops shouldn't mix! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `.each` to assign click event to each `button`. Also, I am not able to identify any `.button` element in your code.

Assuming that you want to attach click event to your `img` with class `popos_img`, you can just directly do it as below. I would suggest few changes in your design too to make it simpler. Below would be your updated design:

```
{% for place in places %}
     <div class="parent"> <!--Wrap this in a parent div-->
        <div class="row col-md-3"> <!--remove id from here as it creates duplicates inside for loop-->
            <!--or create an unique one-->
            <div class="company_img_block company_btn1">
                <img src="{{ place.place_photo }}" class="popos_img" type="button" id="button_{{ place.place_photo }}">
                <div class="company_img_desc">{{ place.title }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="toggled col-md-9 hidden"><!--remove id from here as it creates duplicates inside for loop-->
            <!--or create an unique one-->
            <div id="details_{{ place.place_photo }}">
                <p>
                <b>Description:</b> {{ place.description }}<br/>
                <b>Address:</b> {{ place.address }}<br/>
                <b>Neighborhood:</b> {{ place.neighborhood }}<br/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Your button click event would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $('.button').on('click',function(){
        $(this).closest('div.parent').find('div.toggled').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Also note that, `id's` in `html` should be unique and hence do not generate static id inside `for loop`

Comment: Thanks I think I've gotten much closer, but now nothing is toggled: it's all free flying in the wind. 

If I change 
`<div class="toggled col-md-9 hidden">`
to
`<div class="toggled col-md-9" hidden>`
they toggle, but the js isn't working. And they're now showing up four instead of three across

I added what I now have to a fiddle. Thanks!
https://jsfiddle.net/aroseartist/z1spsxwg/#&togetherjs=7Pm5ffjh0J

Comment: @LoraRose Here is an **[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/z1spsxwg/3/)** for you which has dummy value.. Instead of using `for loop`, I have just replicated 4 images and their respective values. I have slight modification in `js`. Instead of `$('.button').on('click'` you need to place `$('.popos_img').on('click'`.. Let me know if you have any doubts on this..

Comment: We're closer @Guruprasad Rao - I had to add `<script type="text/javscript">` to avoid a load error but otherwise no issues other than it not working! I'm here: [https://jsfiddle.net/aroseartist/yp5zztLf/](https://jsfiddle.net/aroseartist/yp5zztLf/)
The DOM is showing the image as well as all of the details still. I tried playing around with the `.find('div.toggled')` and `.toggleClass('hidden')` per the jQuery docs since the hidden would be removed and added after each request. But, no toggling whatsoever.

Comment: Could you possible do me a favor? Once your page is rendered in browser, jus copy the rendered `html` which your `for loop` creates from the browser console and then paste in fiddle and provide the link.. What ever you have fiddle right now wouldn't be of much help..

Comment: Gladly! It's driving me nutty. Thank you [https://jsfiddle.net/aroseartist/yp5zztLf/](https://jsfiddle.net/aroseartist/yp5zztLf/)

Comment: No no. not this.. :( Once your page is rendered in browser, just right click on one of those `element` and Inspect `element`. Copy that complete `html` and paste in a fiddle please.. Or paste the complete `html` from the page.. :)

Comment: Oy vey. Oops - okay, inspect element copy entire element is here [https://jsfiddle.net/aroseartist/12xLu2wm/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/aroseartist/12xLu2wm/1/) OR the entire page is here[https://jsfiddle.net/aroseartist/z1spsxwg/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/aroseartist/z1spsxwg/4/)

Comment: See, **[its toggling properly right](https://jsfiddle.net/z1spsxwg/5/)**? What problem you are facing?

Comment: Okay it's toootally not toggling on the client side server...would you mind looking over the repo? My containerization went out the door somewhere along the way, but that part I can figure out. You're keeping me from pulling my hair out, truly, thanks. [https://github.com/aroseartist/hiddenGems2](https://github.com/aroseartist/hiddenGems2)

Comment: Just a point here.. For me to work on above repo, I need to set the environment. How about we have Team viewer session, if you would like to, so that I can do it directly in your system? This shouldn't take much time..

Comment: That would be immensely helpful - how best to do that?

Comment: You can mail me your TV details to kshkrao3@gmail.com and it will be good if you select a timing between 9am to 10am IST or 10pm to 12am IST..

Answer (score 0):

Circling back:
So, the crux of the problem was, as usual, simple once the script was working (big thanks to @Guruprasad Rao)

We removed a duplicate jQuery script loader, then realized "text/javscript" was missing the second A!!!

I finally ended up with

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.popos_img', function() {
        $('.parent div.toggled').addClass('hidden');
        var $container = $(this).closest('div.parent');
        $container.find('div.toggled').removeClass('hidden');
    });  
    $(document).on('click', 'div.toggled', function(){
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
    })
</script>'
```